# Embed Yammer into Ionic/Cordova Hybrid app

Tags: html, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, yammer

Just wondering if anyone had done this before, i have used the code that yammer provide in order to embed a certain group or page into an application, here is my class file below:

```
<ion-view view-title="Feed">
  <ion-content>
<body>
  <div id="embedded-feed" style="height:200px;width:100px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: "#embedded-feed",
  network: "MyGroup.com",
  feedType: "group",
  feedId: "111111"});
</script>
</body>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

when i run the page in a browser it shows fine, yet nothing shows when ran on an ios simulator.

Any help is appriciated,
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add https://assets.yammer.com (or maybe even *.yammer.com) to the whitelisted urls in the cordova container, otherwise all communications will be blocked.

Comment: When i click on login button , app get crashed .Is there any way to integrate Yammer in Hybrid app?

Comment: @BenharUpasana did u get this worked and how? If so, can you please share an example for this - My hybrid app is getting crashed when clicked on login button.

Answer (score 0):

yammer embedded-feed is not possible in cordova hybrid app. Use REST APIs to get the message/ feed .